# How I could check if there is a USB inserted or USB removal in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, events, usb

I would like to make a program for windows 7 that checking all the time if there is a USB insertion or USB removal in C/C++, How Could I do this?, Could you give an example code?, thank you

Comment: There is no "C/C++". You do it either in C or in C++. And you'll likely need quite a few Windows API functions for that. What research on the topic have you made so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214768/detecting-usb-insertion-removal-in-c-non-gui-application

Comment: When I put C/C++ is because both works for me. I was reading something about RegisterDeviceNotification but normally, in the Windows examples appears an example with detect insert and removal from CD. I was testing the code the examples of the link above but in mi case I don't need to create a window to run the program with running the program by console is enough for me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6994591/2903452

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works thank you all, this is the code:

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#define USE_CDROM_GUID_ONLY



//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

MSG msg;
void pupu(HWND hwnd);

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg,WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (msg == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
    {
        switch (wParam){
            case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:

                printf("new device connected \n");
                break;
            case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:

                printf("a device has been removed \n");
                break;

        }

    }//if
    else
    cout << "Got msg " << msg << ", " << int(wParam)
    << ", " << int(lParam) << endl;
return 1;
}//WinProc

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
HWND pipi(){
    const char *className = "DevNotifyTest";

    WNDCLASSA wincl = { 0 };
    wincl.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(0);
    wincl.lpszClassName = className;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;



    HWND parent = 0;
#ifdef USE_MESSAGE_ONLY_WINDOW
    parent = HWND_MESSAGE;
#endif
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_TOPMOST, className, className,0, 0, 0, 0, 0,     parent, 0, 0, 0);


    GUID cdromDevIntGuid =
    { 0x53F56308, 0xB6BF, 0x11D0,
    { 0x94, 0xF2, 0x00, 0xA0, 0xC9, 0x1E, 0xFB, 0x8B } };

    DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE_A notifyFilter = { 0 };
    notifyFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(notifyFilter);
    notifyFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
    notifyFilter.dbcc_classguid = cdromDevIntGuid;

    HDEVNOTIFY hDevNotify =
        RegisterDeviceNotificationA(hwnd, &notifyFilter,
#ifndef USE_CDROM_GUID_ONLY
        DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES |
#endif
        DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE);



    return hwnd;


}
void pupu(HWND hwnd){   

        BOOL bRet = PeekMessage(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        Sleep(1000);
}

int main()
{

    HWND hwnd = pipi();
    for (;;){
        pupu(hwnd);
        Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}//main
```

Answer (score 1):

[Registering for Device Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363432%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a sample device notification example.

RegisterDeviceNotification function to register to receive notification messages from the system.

[Detecting Media Insertion or Removal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Windows send WM_DEVICECHANGE messages to top-level windows when new devices or media are added and become available, and when existing devices or media are removed.

Comment: I'm going to try with this focus, I think is that I'm searching